# Unable to cast ObjectContent to HttpContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

The following code **works when I run it from Visual Studio on my laptop**. But when deployed to IIS on a Windows 2016 server I get a 500 error and an Exception (.NET Framework 4.7):

```
ExceptionMessage: "Error getting value from 'Content' on 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'."
ExceptionType   : "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException"

InnerException
ExceptionMessage: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent' to type 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'."
ExceptionType   : "System.InvalidCastException"
```

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    // Entities is the Entity Framework context
    // Sessions is a proprietary table and has nothing to do with ASP.NET sessions
    var content = new Entities().Sessions
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(t =>
        {
            return new
            {
                t.Id,
                t.SessionId,
                t.StartTime,
                t.EndTime
            };
        });

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content    = new ObjectContent(typeof(IEnumerable), content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously using .NET 4.7 on IIS (Windows Server 2016) isn't a good idea. Things started to work when I downgraded my project to 4.6 ...